# vim regex : multi-line edit and controlling the cursor position

Tags: regex, search, vim

A text file is formatted like this:

```
Section 4 Area B Unit 20
   stuff i don't need...
   stuff i don't need...
   45990 - Title of Project that I want to save
   line of text I need to keep
   line of text I need to keep
   2010-11 this line (starting with 2010) is not needed
   stuff i don't need

Section 589 Area C Unit 1005
   stuff i don't need...
   stuff i don't need...
   45990 - Title of Project that I want to save
   line of text I need to keep
   line of text I need to keep
   2010-11 this line (starting with 2010) is not needed
   stuff i don't need
```

and these sections repeat by the hundreds.  The "stuff i don't need" lines are actually about 30 or so.  I need to keep the association of the "Section..." line, "Title..." line and "line of text I need to keep" related to each other.  So I was hoping to first destruct the text document down (linewise) to the stuff I need before operating on it further (character-wise).  So I wrote this:

```
g!/\Section\s\d*\sArea\s\h\sUnit\s\d*\n\|^\s\{3}\zs\d*\s-\_.*\ze2010-11/d
```

After deleting I get the "Section.." line and the "Title..." line, but never the subsequent lines underneath the "Title.." line.  Those subsequent lines vary from 4 to 8 lines, but the "2010-11" line is consistent and always what I no longer want.

You can see I tried using zs and ze to select what I do not want deleted.  I think the selection is working because if I change the command to "2011-12" then there is no match and the (OR) half of the command does not return a result.

I think the fault might be the cursor position(?), but I'm not sure and my effort to fix that has failed.

Can anyone see my error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl.

```
:silent! g/^Section/+ , /^\s\+\d\+ -/- d
:g/^\s\+2010/ , -/\nSection\|\%$/ d
```

Comment: Thanks @adscriven, this was very helpful.  Question: Does the minus sign in the second line "-\nSection" say to go up one line before finding the newline starting with Section? If so, why doesn't changing it to a + sign cause it to go down one line before doing the same?

Comment: It does! The minus tells vim to back up one line before searching for the following regexp. This is necessary in case your `2010-11 ...` lines don't have any following `stuff i don't need`. You have to back up one line to find the following `Section ...` or the last line in the file (`\%$`).

Answer (score 1):

`:g` finds every line matching start of the pattern, `!` will revert the selection and command will get applied to these lines.

Would something like `g/^Section.../normal! j2dd3jd}` do?

If not you can use a search for the Title line inside normal!
You may need to enclose it in "exec" but may be much simpler to write a function.

Do you really need to use vim? Seems like job for Perl to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't know Perl.  Also, I am using two vim plugins to access and dump a webpage into a vim buffer for editing; not sure what in Perl would do the same.  I think I can stay with vim and change my approach.  The g! and v reversing of g is known, that's why the /d deletes everything but the intended selection.  I do not understand why the subsequent 3+ lines below "Title.." do not show up after being run - even though they seem to be found in the command.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do t, I'm sure.  I think this sequence of commands should work (ignoring comment lines that begin with double quote):

```
" global delete of line below 'Section' to line before 'Title'
g/^\s*Section/+1;/Title/-1delete
" global delete from date line to line before 'Section'
g/^\s*\d\d\d\d-\d\d/;/^\s*Section/-1delete
" go to top line of buffer
gg
" delete last chunk, from final date to last line
/^\s*\d\d\d\d-\d\d/;$delete
```

Comment: Thanks @Herbert Sitz, I learned from your response.  adscriven's response was more specific and used a bit more appropriate regexes - but essentially you guys did the same thing (just as you said, "many ways").  Merry Christmas -> Happy New Year! :)